# IT Hit WebDAV AJAX Library on Chrome becomes unresponsive

Tags: google-chrome, ms-word, webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I am experiencing an issue with opening a Microsoft Office Document, using IT Hit WebDAV AJAX library, in latest Chrome 39.0. running on Windows OS. It is a sporadic issue that occurs only in Chrome, and it happens when one opens a document multiple times. Word instance won't start, the page freezes and browser becomes unresponsive, and Chrome suggests killing the page. The only solution is restarting the browser, which solves the issue.

I have tried opening a document in Chrome on Mac OS X, and it is working fine. So are Mozilla and Safari on all operating systems. It seems to be a Chrome + Windows issue only. 
Has anyone experienced this issue and is there a fix?

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. It's the company that advises us to post questions here regarding library issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Office plug-in that opens the document displays a warning popup "Some files can harm your computer.", which is a modeless dialog:

[image]

If you quickly click on a link that opens the document more than one time the dialog will hide behind the main web browser window. As a result the web browser window is blocked.

You need to switch to that dialog and confirm or reject document opening, otherwise after some time Chrome will ask you if to kill the page or wait.

Note that there is no way to avoid that dialog, this is a built-in MS Office functionality as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will only work good with ITHitWebDAV if the user has got Office 2013 or superior.

Google is blocking all Java applets and NPAPIs now, so good luck with that. I just detect the browser of the user that wants to edit a document, and if it's chrome, I warn him to change to another browser like Firefox with a modal, and that's all.

Very poor support between Chrome and ITHitWebDAV, and no much you can do about it.